# Where on the border of convergence circle series converges and where diverges?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I have power series of $ \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} (\ln k)^{\alpha} z^k$. Alpha is a parameter. I've found the radius of convergence. R = 1. If $alpha \geq 0$ then series diverges for z from boundary ($|z| = 1$). For $alpha \lt 0$: if $z = -1$ or $z=\pm i$ series converges as oscillating. But what we can say about other points from boundary?